# ODBC config files on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, odbc

I am trying to set up an ODBC connection on Ubuntu.  I've been swimming in various config files.  Could someone please remind me the directory in which the odbc config file is stored? It is called the odbc.ini file, correct?  And is there another config file I have to add or that is the only file that controls ODBC?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually in `/etc/odbcinst.ini , /etc/odbc.ini and ~/.odbc.ini`

[ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ODBCConfig.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you installed `unixodbc`, the config files could be stored in different locations. You can run `odbcinst -j` to get the configured locations for you system.